# DataStructure For 2-Dimentional Linked List

Tags: java

We create our own CustomLinkedList by creating a Link class , which will have refrence nextLink.

```
public class CustomLink{
   public int val;
   public CustomLink nextLink;
  }

public class CustomLinkedList{

public CustomLink root = null;
//insert , retrieve,delete methods..
}
```

If we wanted to have a 2-D linked list of our own, how can I proceed?
What changes do i need to make in my Link class?

Comment: By 2-D linked list, do you mean bi directional traversing?

Comment: Can you elaborate what 2-D means ? Linked list of linked lists like list<list<val>> ? Doubly linked bi directional like val1<<val2>>val3?

Comment: Assuming that you are indeed talking about a true 2D linked list ("linked matrix"?) where you can not only go left/right but also up/down, may I ask why one would ever need it? (Just curious.)

Comment: To put values from spreadsheet

Comment: was trying to solve an experiment problem given in LinkedList chapter of data structure and alogrithm in java

Comment: @Ullas To put the values from spreadsheet? can you edit your post and clearly mention the input format, how you want linked list to fit in there?

Comment: Would one really want to store a spreadsheet as linked list(s) though? Assuming that one wants random access to it, an ArrayList of ArrayLists or a Dictionary of a coordinate object (depending on whether or not the data is sparse) would probably be more appropriate for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

When performing design tasks on containers I'd recommend to follow general Java [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) approach. Java has [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) interface and this should be good starting point for you. Of course unless you have some good reason not to follow but even in this case I'd carefully review existing works. Implementing standard interfaces gives you lot of advantages.